# How to refactor an imperative function recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I have an HL7 MLLP message building class I'd like to refactor. The way HL7 over MLLP works is there are multiple fields, usually delimited by the `|` character. Within the field, there can be lists, delimited by `^`, and within those lists there can be lists, delimited by `&`.

So for example, the following structure:

```
message = ['foo', 
            ['bar', 'baz', 
              ['a', 'b', 'c']
            ], 
           'comment']
```

will be serialized to the message:

`serialized = "foo|bar^baz^a&b&c|comment"`

I've written a simple class whose constructor arguments indicate where in the list of fields you want to place some data, as well as the data itself. The `__repr__` method is defined for easy use of these objects in f-strings.

This is the class:

```
class SegmentBuilder:
    def __init__(self, segment_type, *args):
        if not isinstance(segment_type, str):
            raise ValueError("Segment type must be a string")
        self.state = {0: segment_type}
        for index, value in args:
            self.state[index] = value
        self.fields = [None for _ in range(1 + max(self.state.keys()))]

    def __repr__(self):
        # Do a Depth-first string construction
        # Join first list using ^, second list using &
        # This is ugly, but will work for now
        # Could do better with an actual recursive depth-based approach
        def clean(obj):
            return str(obj) if obj is not None else ''
        for index, value in self.state.items():
            if not isinstance(value, list):
                self.fields[index] = value
            else:
                subfields = []
                for subfield in value:
                    if not isinstance(subfield, list):
                        subfields.append(clean(subfield))
                    else:
                        subsubfields = []
                        for subsubfield in subfield:
                            subsubfields.append(clean(subsubfield))
                        subfields.append('&'.join(subsubfields))
                self.fields[index] = '^'.join(subfields)

        return '|'.join([clean(field) for field in self.fields])
```

Now, there's clearly a recursive refactoring trying to leap out of this, probably involving some list comprehension as well. I thought it might involve passing an iterator based on the sequence of delimiter characters, eg `"|^&"`, but the base case had me confused (since you would have to catch `StopIteration`, and then maybe signal to the caller via returning None?). Any guidance on this recursive refactor would be very helpful!

Comment: Is the second `bar` in a serialized message supposed to be `baz`?

Comment: It is! That was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand all of the rules, but if you have only 3
delimiters, one per level in the hierarchy, then the base case is the level
number or a non-list type. Here's a sketch of one recursive implementation:

```
DELIMITERS = ['|', '^', '&']

def serialize(level, xs):
    if isinstance(xs, list) and level < len(DELIMITERS):
        return DELIMITERS[level].join(
            serialize(level + 1, x)
            for x in xs
        )
    else:
        # Base case: adjust as needed.
        return xs
```

I suspect your messages might have more variety in the leaf-node data types
(are ints and floats allowed?). If so, you might need to use `return str(xs)`
instead.

Comment: Brilliant! I like the exception-free approach, also how you constructed the base case conditions!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth saying: I like the recursive implementation better, but it's not the only approach. Consider: you could just do one outer pass for each of the separators, like this:

```
from typing import Sequence, Any, Union

StringsOrSeqs = [Union[str, Sequence[Any]]]


def flatten(to_convert: StringsOrSeqs, sep: str) -> StringsOrSeqs:
    for sub in to_convert:
        if isinstance(sub, Sequence) and not isinstance(sub, str):
            for x in sub[:-1]:
                yield x
                yield sep
            yield sub[-1]
        else:
            yield sub


message = (
    'foo',
    (
        'bar', 'baz',
        (
            'a', 'b', 'c',
        ),
    ),
    'comment',
)

to_convert = [message]
for sep in '|^&':
    to_convert = list(flatten(to_convert, sep))
serialized = ''.join(to_convert)
print(serialized)
```